# MS Word: images and lists break paragraph formatting

Tags: microsoft-word

I've set up styles so that my paragraphs under level 4 headings stick together. To this end, I've set "Widow/Orphan control", "Keep with next", and "Keep lines together" for both the 4th heading style and the Normal text style, which follows 4th headings.
This works well, but when images and lists are present in the paragraphs, this breaks the rule and I get the heading separated from the paragraph and sometimes short lists are split across 2 pages.
Sorry I've had to blur text but I kept formatting on to help resolve this.
[image: Split heading-text]
The image above shows the 4th level heading separated from the rest, which never happens when there is only text involved. The image is set to be aligned with text.
[image: Split list]
The image above shows a 3 item list split in the middle.
I've tried lots of things, including messing with 3rd level headings parameters but to no avail.

Comment: Hi Harnex, welcome to writing.se! Take the [tour] when you get a chance and visit the [help] for more information. While this question is on-topic here and you may get a good answer, you might get a better response on [su]. That site has a stronger technical focus and gets lots of word questions every day. Good luck and happy writing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s a bit hard for me to see, but it appears that every paragraph on each page has a black square in the left margin, indicating that the “Keep with next” or "Keep lines together” attribute or both is applied to every paragraph. Word can’t keep each paragraph with the next if they won’t all fit on one page. It appears that you need to reduce the amount of text to which “Keep with next” is applied. For example, if the bulleted item above the 3.2.3.2 heading has “Keep with next” applied, it shouldn’t: it doesn’t need to be with the following heading. I suggest taking “Keep with next” out of the bullet styles and whatever style is used for inline graphics. Then apply “Keep with next” to every item in a bulleted list except the last. That will keep the list together but not force it to be with the next heading.